# How to classify DNS packets coming to clients as spoofed or not?

Tags: network

Without being bothered by a DNS server that is using newer version of the DNS protocol. I want to monitor DNS packets on client machines and want to classify them as being spoofed or not.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably impossible to look at a single DNS packet and know if it is spoofed or not. But, if this is a DNS reply packet to a system without a matching DNS request a short time before than this is probably spoofing. And if there is a DNS request originating from the machine but the incoming DNS reply does answer the DNS query but does not match in the DNS request in port and id than this is probably a spoofing attempt too, especially if there are lots of these mismatching packets.

Comment: would be pretty stupid spoofing if you could tell a real packet from a spoofed one easily, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: blind spoofing DNS can be done by mass sending packets with different ids and ports in the hope the one of these packets matches the original DNS request. Thus getting lots of such non-matching packets is a sign that one should probably not trust the seemingly correct answer too, since it was only correct by chance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are monitoring DNS requests on your clients, then I would have thought any request where the source IP is that of the client machine would be not spoofed, and anything else would be spoofed.

From a server perspective, it is a bit more complicated, but possible to a point:

- in terms of traffic monitoring, you might be able to get something out of checking out the TTLs of incoming packets - if the TTL suggests a request has crossed more hops than you know you have in your network, there is a chance it might be spoofed (or you just identified something to look into in terms of routing)
- source port could help to a point - notably, anything that looked like server-to-server traffic and was not from a server you knew about might point to something untoward happening. If you have a known range of ports clients are configure to use (e.g. 10000 to 30000), then anything outside that range could be worth investigating.
- depending on the details of your setup, you might be able to gain some insight from where you traffic coming from (e.g. an external-facing firewall is recording incoming packets with a spoofed source IP, or incoming interface for a request isn't correct
- their may be a process of elimination you can apply: is the source IP and/or range in use within your network? Is the specific source IP known to be active on a legitimate client (i.e. does DHCP/ActiveDirectory/something else correlate this is real client)?

Some more details on your setup and motivations could help to think of some other areas, but hopefully the ones above are of some use.

**Edit**:

Reading the comments, I realised I misunderstood the question as being about spoofed requests, rather than spoofed responses.

As pointed out by other, for DNS responses, things are more complicated. 
Of the suggestions above, only looking at TTL seems like it would even be worth considering.

You might be able to put something in place for your internal DNS records (maybe comparing internal DNS responses to expected values).
But that seems like a small part of the overall issue, for which a solution is rather harder to find.

I guess one other thing you could look into is profiling the DNS TTLs (as well as IP TTLs) - significant sites like google, facebook, etc have fairly low TTLs (300 seconds) for A records, for example, and you might expect someone attempting to poison caches to have an interest in using far higher TTLs for these records.

For A records, you might also gain something from actually analysing the responses - trying to check those using GeoIP, for example, could help.

How effective all that would be (versus how much work it would be to maintain) is definitely a question, though.

Comment: "any request where the source IP is that of the client machine... " is nowhere near sufficient.  Spoofing based DNS poisoning attacks have been shown to succeed through brute force - spraying thousands of responses (one of which will have the correct tuple) and hoping to win the race against the actual DNS response.

Comment: as Jeff K pointed out DNS poisioning, i am trying to find the solution towards DNS cache poisioning attack by monitoring DNS packets on the client....suppose a situation where attacker attacks on the DNS server and changes the entry in cache then whenever client asks for that domain, DNS server will provide legitimate DNS response having illegitimate ip address for that domain, so in such cases how source ip checking will help since it is changing entry on server...?

Comment: as the situation mentioned in above comment, i would like to know the way to detect DNS packet with bad response

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue...thanks for your answer, i think it is considerable but what if the DNS request for the domain having illegitimate information on DNS server is came after long time when TTL is low then our monitoring system will consider it as legitimate (if only TTL is taken into consideration).

Comment: i was thinking about creating local database of domain name & ip addresses having trusted information. But where can i get the trusted information? @iwaseatenbyagrue

Answer (score 0):

Detecting spoofed UDP DNS replies is complex. You can consider doing DNS requests only over TCP and reject DNS replies via UDP with a firewall rule. Since TCP requires a three-way handshake, it's much hard to spoof.

Comment: we will get legitimate DNS response from DNS server but what if DNS server information is altered by attacker (DNS spoofing attack) then it will provide illegitimate information with legitimate DNS response packet then how to ensure that the DNS server is giving correct information?..@Teun Vink

Comment: The only real solution here is DNSSEC. UDP spoofing is very hard to detect, using validation would mean spoofed replies will be discarded.

Comment: DNSSEC is server side solution but i want to monitor on client side @Teun Vink

Comment: DNSSEC is a protocol between server and client, it's not specifically server side protocol. Your client can detect spoofed DNS replies by verifying answers for DNSSEC signed zones. If the validation fails, this could indicate spoofing (or misconfiguration on the authoritative DNS server).